# What is the impact of unused libraries that are included using the -l flag?

Tags: c, gcc, include, compiler-flags

I am compiling a C project with many source files. Not all of them need all the external libraries I'm using, e.g. `math` library (`gcc` flag `-lm`), but including it for all files results in a simpler makefile.

What is the impact on compilation/performance if I include libraries that are unused by some/most of the source files?

Comment: Try with and without and compare. My bet is for zero impact.

Comment: Mostly an extra time spent in linking. The linker still must read TOC to make sure there is nothing to pull from the library.